# Custom validator does not set parameter values to the properties of the validator in Struts2

Tags: java, validation, struts2

I'm trying to build a custom validator in Struts2 (2.3.16) as follows.

```
package validator;

import actions.DiscountAction;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationException;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.validators.ValidatorSupport;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public final class DiscountDateValidator extends ValidatorSupport
{
    private DateTime startDate;
    private DateTime endDate;

    //Getters and setters.

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException
    {
        System.out.println("startDate = "+startDate);
        System.out.println("endDate = "+endDate);
        System.out.println((o instanceof DiscountAction));
    }
}
```

The `validators.xml` file looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator Config 1.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-config-1.0.dtd">

<validators>
    <validator name="discountDateValidator" 
               class="validator.DiscountDateValidator"/>
</validators>
```

And this validator is used in an action which is as follows.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value="struts-default")
public final class DiscountAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ValidationAware, ModelDriven<Discount>
{
    @Autowired
    private final transient DiscountService discountService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Discount entity=new Discount();

    @Override
    public Discount getModel() {
        return entity;
    }

    @Validations(
        customValidators={
            @CustomValidator(type="discountDateValidator", parameters={
                @ValidationParameter(name="startDate", value="${entity.discountStartDate}"), 
                @ValidationParameter(name="endDate", value="${entity.discountEndDate}")}, 
            message="xxx zzz aaa")})
    @Action(value = "AddDiscount",
    results = {
        @Result(name=ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type="redirectAction", params={"namespace", "/admin_side", "actionName", "Discount", "currentPage", "${currentPage}", "message", "${message}", "editId", "${editId}", "status", "${status}"}),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Discount.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs={@InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params={"params.acceptParamNames", "editId, discountId, discountCode, discountPercent, discountStartDate, discountEndDate, currentPage, rowCount, totalPages, status", "validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true"})})
    public String insert(){
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The `validate()` method of `DiscountDateValidator` is invoked on submission of the form, the values of `startDate` and `endDate` are however, always `null`, `o instanceof DiscountAction` evaluates to `true`.

What am I overlooking here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `${discountStartDate}` and `${discountEndDate}` (the value attribute of `@ValidationParameter`) are directly set to the string properties of the validator which we need to parse manually using the `Object parse(String expression, Class type)` method in the `validate()` method.

Such expressions are evaluated as OGNL expressions by the `parse()` method. The validator after these changes is as follows.

```
package validator;

import actions.DiscountAction;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationException;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.validators.ValidatorSupport;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public final class DiscountDateValidator extends ValidatorSupport
{
    private String startDate; //Set to ${discountStartDate}
    private String endDate;   //Set to ${discountEndDate}

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(String endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object o) throws ValidationException
    {
        DateTime discountStartDate = (DateTime)parse(startDate, DateTime.class);
        DateTime discountEndDate = (DateTime)parse(endDate, DateTime.class);

        System.out.println("startDate = "+discountStartDate);
        System.out.println("endDate = "+discountEndDate);
        System.out.println((o instanceof DiscountAction));

        //Perform validation as required using these values.
    }
}
```

`getFieldValue("discountStartDate", o)` and `getFieldValue("discountEndDate", o)` also work that can retrieve the field values directly (I'm not sure about any side effects of this method in such kind of validators).

<sub>`${entity.discountStartDate}` and `${entity.discountStartDate}` are not required (`entity` should be excluded as it is included in the question).</sub>